# java split string with regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to split string by setting all non-alphabet as separator.

```
String[] word_list = line.split("[^a-zA-Z]");
```

But with the following input

> 11:11 Hello World

word_list contains many **empty string** before "hello" and "world"

Please kindly tell me why. Thank You.

Comment: Do you expect as result with `11:11 Hello World` as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your regular expression matches each individual non-alpha character.  It would be like separating

```
",,,,,,Hello,World"
```

on commas.

You will want an expression that matches an entire sequence of non-alpha characters at once such as:

```
line.split("[^a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*")
```

I still think you will get one leading empty string with your example since it would be like separating `",Hello,World"` if comma were your separator.

Comment: Thanks blackcompe.  I thought it would, but wasn't sure since I've used some regex implementations support + and others that don't.  Wasn't sure about Java's String.split().

Comment: Finally, I first replace the heading non-alphabet character with empty string and then call split() with this regex :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's your string, where each `^` character shows a match for `[^a-zA-Z]`:

```
11:11 Hello World
^^^^^^     ^
```

The `split` method finds each of these matches, and basically returns all substrings between the `^` characters. Since there's six matches before any useful data, you end up with 5 empty substrings before you get the string `"Hello"`.

To prevent this, you can manually filter the result to ignore any empty strings.

Comment: I like ur explanation as it is very clear.
But I can only give one tick,sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Will the following do?

```
String[] word_list = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]","").replaceAll(" +", " ").trim().split("[^a-zA-Z]");
```

What I am doing here is removing all non-alphabet characters before doing the split and then replacing multiple spaces by a single space.